# Counting duplicates and removing them in MySQL SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this one.

I have a *Cars Database* with a *Class* field that when selecting all entries, it will have duplicates of each *Class* value. What I need to do with that is to count all of duplicates for each *Class* value and then remove the duplicates to only display each *Class* value once with a custom fields with the counted amount.

```
Class  
-----  
A3  
A3  
A3  
A3  
B2  
B2
```

To become:

```
Class | Count  
------+---------  
A3    | 4  
B2    | 2
```

I could imagine something contain the `Count()` method, but I have no idea how I could have it count only the duplicate values and return the values separately for each Class value?

Thanks in advance for any help in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Class,COUNT(1) "Count"
FROM Cars GROUP BY Class
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Comment: I think `COUNT(1)` is outdated. Try `COUNT(*)`, which reads better.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Hey, I am 47 yrs old. I still use `COUNT(1)`. Give an old guy a break.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I got dragged through a dark Oracle back alley and mauled last year over this  : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2514/877

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. This will show you only the records with the count of greater than one, it you want a list of all records then remove the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT class, count(class) CountClass
FROM cars
GROUP BY class
HAVING count(class) > 1
```

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I am guessing on the `HAVING` based on the OP but it isn't exactly clear.

Comment: The last part of the question says : `how I could have it count only the duplicate values and return the values separately for each Class value`. I guess Classes whose count is 1 would not fit this description. You having `HAVING` make sense.