# Counting duplicates among multiple columns and removing them in MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table in a MySQL database:

```
number | string
-------+-------
318    | no
504    | no
318    | yes
504    | no
60     | yes
```

I want to count occurences and remove duplicates, adding the count to the remaining row in a `SELECT` statement:

```
number | string | count
-------+--------+------
60     | yes    | 1
318    | no     | 1
318    | yes    | 1
504    | no     | 2
```

Despite the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638602/counting-duplicates-and-removing-them-in-mysql-select-statement), I can't wrap my head around what to count to achieve this result when I have more than one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want multiple columns in your `GROUP BY` clause.  This should work:

```
SELECT number, string, COUNT( number ) AS count
FROM foo
GROUP BY number, string
ORDER BY number, string
```

Comment: Yes, it should return the same result.  I usually try to count primary key fields or fields I'm already selecting because I *believe* it can sometimes affect performance.  There's a better discussion of that here: http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/